# Javascript setDate issues

Tags: javascript

I am reading a `value(n)` from a form, and then making the `enddate` to be `n` days after `startdate(today)`.

```
var closure_days=F.CLOSURE_DAYS.read();
var enddate = new Date();
var startdate=new Date();
startdate.getDate();
enddate.setDate(enddate.getDate() + closure_days);
alert(closure_days);
alert(startdate);
alert(enddate);
```

I just checked the values, `startdate` and `closure_days` seems to hold the proper values, but on addition, the `enddate` is not proper.

Here is an example.

```
Startdate : Fri Nov 8 13:34:55 UTC+0530 2013
Closure_days : 30
Enddate : Mon Feb 8 13:34:55 UTC+0530 2016
```

What might be the reason for this? I think it is adding the month instead of date.
Would very much appreciate your help on this one.

Comment: Have a look at [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) if you have to fight with Date arithmetics.

Comment: Works fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/uNUX8/ Are you sure that's the code you have? (For example the `startdate.getDate()` line does nothing.)

Comment: @Juhana:Yes I am very sure, I dont use the start date concept, I just added that line to check if the date is being picked properly. I only make use of Enddate in my code.

Comment: Does the link I gave also not work for you? Which browser are you using?

Comment: @Juhana Thanks for all the help, I got the problem, the value I was trying to pick was a String and hence the problem, changed the data type to Number and its working fine now.